# Combine textures into one - For Tabletop Simulator

Tags: texturing

I have downloaded an object from a website that includes the textures.  Following a tutorial, I was able to put the textures on the various parts of the object.  They had a separate texture file for the Head, Torso and Legs.  Everything looked Ok and I saved the object.

When I imported the object into tabletop simulator, the textures were missing.  I can only add ONE texture to a model in TTS, if I load one, the others dont have color.  Does anyone know how I can fix this?  Im a total newb at Blender and not much better at TTS.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57531/fbx-export-why-there-are-no-materials-or-textures/57541#57541

Answer (score 1):

If anyone has an automated way of compositing them I would love to hear about it my self, but so far as I know the unfortunate answer is it has to be done manually.  The way I've always had to do it is to open the three separate textures together as layers in a photoshop type program (I typically use gimp) and arrange them as different squares on a bigger single image.  If at all possible i would make the canvas exactly twice the size of the origonal images and arrange the tiles on there with out resizing as that will help with the next step a little.  after that you have to open the model back up in blender and resize/move around the normal map so they line up with the textures on the new single composite image.  If everything went smoothly this is just a matter of selecting them all scaling to .5 and moving them around as a group till it lines up about right.  if each of the three images was a different size however, which often happens, it can get a bit more fiddly resizing and placing.

P.S.  One thing I forgot to add since you mentioned parts not having color.  the color slider in tts will only change the color to the first "material" the object mentions which can be handy if you want to only have say the base or a specific item of clothing on a character to change color.  so in blender which ever material is at the top of the list will be the one affected.  In the sample pic below I want the scales to be able to be set different colors so I have material.004 which is the scale pattern set at the top of the list
[image][image]

Answer (score 0):

Update: finally did find a tutorial on automating the remap, though fair warning baking has its own sets of other issues.  second link is same process but for 2.8 interface

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9airvjDaVh4

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MH7Xdol5erw